# How to use danvk re-orderable columns with dynamically created tables?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement the [danvk](http://www.danvk.org/wp/dragtable/) draggable table Javascript, and while I've been successful using it for tables actually in the html source, when I try to use it with tables I'm creating in Javascript code, it isn't applied to those tables.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is invoke `dragtable.makeDraggable(tableElement);​​​` on a `table` dom node after it has been injected.

Consider the following example code:

**HTML**

```
​<div id="tableDiv"></div>
```

**JavaScript** (the last line here is the crucial one)

```
var tableStr = '<table id="table" class="draggable" border="1"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Color</th></tr><tr><td>Dan</td><td>1984-07-12</td><td>Blue</td></tr><tr><td>Alice</td><td>1980-07-22</td><td>Green</td></tr><tr><td>Ryan</td><td>1990-09-23</td><td>Orange</td></tr><tr><td>Bob</td><td>1966-04-21</td><td>Red</td></tr></table>',
    tableDiv = document.getElementById('tableDiv'),
    table;
tableDiv.innerHTML = tableStr;
table = document.getElementById('table');
dragtable.makeDraggable(table);​​​
```

Check out a working demo of this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mKm9G/).

Comment: Adam,

You're a bloody star.  I owe you a beer :).

Cheers!